# how to reverse the symbols and keep the alignment with tikz circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I want to draw an electrical circuit, inverting (mirror) the symbols of the contacts, but when I do, I lose the vertical alignment of the symbols and the lines are no longer horizontal.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,chains,calc,fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\node(Ov) at (0,2em){0V};
\node[make contact={info=$a_i$}] (ai) at (5em,0){};
\node[break contact={info=$b_i$},right=6em of ai,yscale=-1] (Nbi){};
\draw (Ov) |- (ai)  -- (Nbi);

\node[break contact={info=$a_i$},below=2em of ai] (Nai){};
\node[make contact={info=$c_i$},right=13em of Nai,yscale=-1] (ci){};
\node[bulb={info=V}, above right=1em and 6em of ci](V){};
\draw (Ov) |- (Nai) -- (ci);

\node[make contact={info=$b_i$},below=5em of Nbi] (bi){};
\node[break contact={info=$c_i$},right=6em of bi,yscale=-1] (Nci){};

\draw  (Ov) |- (bi) -- (Nci);

\draw (V) --++(-3em,0) |- (Nbi);
\draw (V) --++(-3em,0) |- (Nci);
\draw (V) --++(-3em,0) |- (ci);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, using yscale =-1 in the definition of the contact.
It remains to move the position of the label.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,chains,calc,fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]




\draw (0,-1)coordinate(a0) to [make contact={info=$a_i$,name=ai}]+ (2,0) to [break contact={info=$b_i$,yscale=-1}] +(4,0)coordinate(ab);
\draw (0,-2.5) --+(2,0) to [make contact] +(4,0) to [break contact={info=$c_i$,yscale=-1}] +(6,0) coordinate(vv)to [bulb={info=V}] +(8,0);
\draw (0,-4)coordinate(a2) to [break contact={info=$a_i$,yscale=-1,name=Nai}]+(2,0) --+ (4,0) to [make contact={info=$c_i$}] +(6,0)--(vv);

\draw[dashed] (ai) -- (Nai);

\draw (0,-0.5)node[above]{$0V$} -- (0,-4.5) ;
\draw (8,-0.5)node[above]{$12 V$} -- (8,-4.5) ;
\draw (ab)-|(vv);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```